# 16.04 on ASUS Q551LN - "Using Battery Power" When connected to AC

Tags: 16.04, power-management, battery

I found previous posts regarding this. But, they applied only to version 14. And, the solution was not included as part of the thread.

Does anyone have suggestions for getting ubuntu to recognize when the system is on AC power?

Battery indicator says "Using battery power"... Power options are not helpful in this instance. System is plugged in and the battery power light is illuminated.

Thank you.

There are no other OSs installed on the system at this time.